# jQuery listview with header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile to build a mobile app and I want to show a list of items. The obvious choice here is to use listview. But this list has a header (that contains name of the list) and a footer (that contains summary of the list). To show the header I think I should use list-divider. But I don't know what should I use to show the footer. The list looks something like:

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing as RonnieT mentioned. `<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist"><li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">Sheet: Untitled1</li><!--....--><li id="mylistSummary" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" data-theme="b">Total:</li></ul>` But I was looking for a better alternative. I am going to try the custom css option mentioned by RonnieT.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could use a divider for both?  Depends on your styleing I suppose. You could also style each one uniquely.

Do one at the start and end of your

```
   <ul>
        <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Sheet: Scores</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Total</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing now. I was thinking I could use a better option if there is one available.

Comment: You might almost be best off styling a custom css for an `<li>` class or something

Comment: Yeah. That would be my next step. It seems there is not out-of-the-box support for footer in listview.